# HTML5 Canvas TextBaseline Top looks different in Firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, canvas, html5-canvas

In canvas, while setting textBaseline property to 'top', its rendering differently in chrome and firefox. In chrome, there is a gap between line and the text where as there is no gap in firefox.

Kindly refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/playcanvas.asp?filename=playcanvas_textbaseline) to view in your browser, any help would be thankful.

I also checked [similar issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852) reported long-back. Is there any work-around in firefox to get it work fine?
[image: Render in chrome]

[image: Render in Firefox]

Comment: use alphabetic and set the offset manually or go through FF's sources and fix the bug.

Comment: Actually it seems that the bug is in the other browsers : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852#c20

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the OP that this is an issue and it's peculiar to **Firefox**. Increasingly though, it seems that **Firefox** has adjusted the vertical offset overtime. It was once once about 4 pixels, then 3. Now, it is almost imperceptible. So, I agree with @Kaiido above. Use/set `*object*.textBaseline="alphabetic";` I believe that this is consistent across browsers.