# Placing Text on HTML5 Canvas inconsistent across browsers

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm placing text in an HTML5 canvas. I'm setting the context textAlign value to center and the textBaseline to "hanging"

I'm confused, because safari and chrome and both webkit and the text placement is diffrent even when told to be in the same spot.

Chrome looks correct:
[image: chrome example]

as does firefox
[image: firefox example]

however safari places the text lower (same code)
[image: safari example]

any idea how safari calculates the position differently so I can build an exception for it?

Comment: Which version of safari? And without the actual code it's really hard to help...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407614/html5-canvas-textbaseline-top-looks-different-in-firefox-and-chrome. So chrome would have fixed it, aligning on FF and specs, while others will not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text to fit is a pain. Here is a none standard way to make text fit almost pixel perfect. (width may come inside requested a little and some fonts are just way to out there to measure).

This method renders the text at a large size "100px" and then measures its various parts. You can the fit to a rectangle, with four options that you can see in the demo. T, H and letters like that tend to be slightly shorter than O, G and rounded letters, you can opt to keep the round bits inside or not, you can ignore the tails 'y,j,g' or keep them inside.

The measuring function renders text several times to find the various parts, you can overlap several letters if you want a better sample or a specific font is a pain.

This solution will fit all browsers that have good canvas support.

Sorry about the naming but this particular issue does me in, we get great text in every other browser API so why not canvas????? (secret conspiracy of the SVG camp LOL ;) me thinks

Two functions. First measures the text, and returns an object containing the relevant info, and the second renders text to fit a rectangle. See the code at the bottom how to use it and set the two flags that control the hanging tail and roundy bits.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 800;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);


function superWTFCanvasTextMessure(font){ // just the font name please.....
    var c = document.createElement("canvas"); // make canvas
    var ctx1 = c.getContext("2d"); // get the thing that draw the stuff
    ctx1.font = "100px "+font; // big font
    ctx1.textAlign = "center";  // put it in the middle
    ctx1.textBaseline = "middle";
    // draw text nice and solid...
    ctx1.fillText("lp",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("lp",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("lp",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("lq",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("lg",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("lj",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    // get the pixels as words
    
    var data= new Uint32Array(ctx1.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data.buffer);
    var top = 0;
    while(data[top++] === 0);  // find the first pixel on from the top;
    var tail = data.length - 1;
    while(data[tail--] === 0); // find the first pixel on from the bottom;
     
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear up the mess
    // and now for the Base  draw text nice and solid...
    ctx1.fillText("T",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("T",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("T",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("T",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("T",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    // get the pixels as words
    data= new Uint32Array(ctx1.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data.buffer);
    var bum = data.length - 1;
    while(data[bum--] === 0); // find the first pixel on from the bottom;

    // and the round bits the poke out in all the wrong places.
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear up the mess
    // and now for the Base  draw text nice and solid...
    ctx1.fillText("O",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("J",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("?",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("G",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    ctx1.fillText("O",Math.floor(c.width/2),Math.floor(c.height/2));
    // get the pixels as words
    data= new Uint32Array(ctx1.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data.buffer);
    var head = 0;
    while(data[head++] === 0); // find the first pixel on from the bottom;
    var theOtherBit = data.length - 1;
    while(data[theOtherBit--] === 0); // find the first pixel on from the bottom;

    
    return {
        body: Math.floor(bum / canvas.width) - Math.floor(top / canvas.width)+1,
        all : Math.floor(tail / canvas.width) - Math.floor(top / canvas.width)+1,
        offset : Math.floor(c.height/2) - Math.floor(top / canvas.width),
        t2A : Math.floor(theOtherBit / canvas.width) - Math.floor(head / canvas.width)+1,
        t2t : Math.floor(tail / canvas.width) - Math.floor(head / canvas.width)+1,
        offsetHead : Math.floor(c.height/2) - Math.floor(head / canvas.width),
        font : ctx1.font,
    };
}

function drawPixelPerfectTextTheHardWay(text,left,top,width,height,sWTFDesc){
    var sy,offy;
    ctx.font = sWTFDesc.font; // set up the same font as measured. (dont worry it will be scaled and can be any size but if not measure at 100 px this will not work as well)
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    var w = ctx.measureText(text).width;  // get the width
    if(sWTFDesc.bumsDown){
        if(sWTFDesc.extrasIn){
            sy =  height/ sWTFDesc.t2A;   // get the height scale
        }else{
            sy =  height/ sWTFDesc.body;   // get the height scale
        }
    }else{
        if(sWTFDesc.extrasIn){
            sy =  height/ sWTFDesc.t2t;   // get the height scale
        }else{
            sy =  height/ sWTFDesc.all;   // get the height scale
        }
        
    }
    var sx = width / w; // get the x scale
    if(sWTFDesc.extrasIn){
        offy = sWTFDesc.offset * sy; // get top offset
    }else{
        offy = sWTFDesc.offset * sy; // get the correct offset
    }
    // set up the tranform
    ctx.setTransform(sx,0,0,sy,left + width / 2, top + offy);
    ctx.fillText(text,0,0);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // reset the tranform to the default..
    // all diddly done..
}


ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
var superFontDesc = superWTFCanvasTextMessure("arial");


ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(10,200,700,140);
drawPixelPerfectTextTheHardWay("mind p & q's ? j,g",10,200,700,140,superFontDesc);

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.strokeRect(20,400,700,120);
superFontDesc.bumsDown = true;
drawPixelPerfectTextTheHardWay("test this Jimmy!!",20,400,700,120,superFontDesc);

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.strokeRect(20,20,700,140);
superFontDesc.bumsDown = true;
superFontDesc.extrasIn= true;

drawPixelPerfectTextTheHardWay("test this Jimmy!!",20,20,700,140,superFontDesc);

ctx.fillStyle = "#a50";
ctx.strokeRect(20,570,700,140);
superFontDesc.bumsDown = false;
superFontDesc.extrasIn= true;

drawPixelPerfectTextTheHardWay("????&GGhjqgy",20,570,700,140,superFontDesc);
ctx.font = "20px arial";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText("Round bits in and tails hanging.",10,174);
ctx.fillText("Round bits out and tails in.",10,354);
ctx.fillText("Round bits out and tails hanging.",10,540);
ctx.fillText("Round bits out and tails in.",10,724);
```

Comment: I didn't read all, but why do you use `textBaseline = "middle"` while the only textbaseline all UAs do agree on is alphabetic ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/mygrV.png

Comment: I could have used any baseline, why i used middle is that it is was simpler to know all the text would fit in the temp canvas, I am not sure how much the tails hang down, and I did not want to put too much effort into it. Plus the aim is to fit inside the rectangle. I presume the text size is the same no matter what the base line, and if there is a need for higher precision then the text can be measured at 200px or 400px (note I added a 1pix kludge factor Chrome Canary 55) And I really should have sampled more letters (only did T for baseline to inside top)

Comment: this is a great JS solution, I'll have to try it out. I ended up giving up and just doing an AJAX call to an Imagemagick script to make the text and then return it as a base64 image to the canvas.